# Break ranges into rows Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, rows, break

I have an input like this:

```
Start     End
1         100
```

I would link to break each range into rows:

```
ID
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
100
```

I'm trying to get this output in TERADATA, can you guys help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this a row in a table? Is there a know maximum range, i.e. number of rows returned?

Comment: There is no maximum range and yes the ranges are rows in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teradata's proprietary `EXPAND ON` syntax is for creating *time series*, but can used for your task, too. Assuming TD16.20+ this can be further simplified using a *time series* function:

If start and end are positiv INTegers:

```
select t.*
   ,TD_TIME_BUCKET_NUMBER(time '00:00:00.000000+00:00', begin(pd), microseconds(1)) - 1 -- TD 16.20
from mytable as t
expand on -- works on date/time only -> convert int to period
   period(time '00:00:00.000000+00:00' + (interval '0.000001' second * start_)
         ,time '00:00:00.000001+00:00' + (interval '0.000001' second * end_)
         ) as pd
```

For BIGINT it's a bit more complex and must be nested:

```
select dt.*
   ,start_ + rownum - 1
from
 (
   select t.*
      ,TD_TIME_BUCKET_NUMBER(timestamp '0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000+00:00', begin(pd), microseconds(1) ) as rownum
   from mytable as t
   expand on -- works on date/time only -> convert int to period
      period(timestamp '0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000+00:00'
            ,timestamp '0001-01-01 00:00:00.000001+00:00' + (interval '0.000001' second * (end_ - start_))
            ) as pd 
 ) as dt
 ;
```

This allows creating up to 9,999,999,999 rows, if you need more (up to 863,999,999,999,999) you might switch to an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND, but then you should better rethink you data model :-)

Comment: I tried to adapt your script to my need but with no success. Can you tell me please how to do it? I mean, how to use the EXPAND function with numbers?

Comment: Simply replace `start` and `end` with your columns.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I'm having this error :

SELECT Failed.  [6977] Invalid Period value constructor. The beginning and ending bounds must have the same DateTime data type.

Comment: Nevermind. I just resolved the issue by converting my columns to INTEGER (they were VARCHAR).

It's working now, thank you very much.

Comment: It's me again. When the difference between START & END exceeds 999 999 rows, it is always returning 0 rows using what you suggested (the second script). Do you have an idea why?

Comment: This seems to be a bug, please open an incident. I edited my question and added a workaround, which is also simpler and works between 0 and 9,999,999,999

Comment: When trying to adapt your script, I'm having this error:
"[9103] Invalid Period value constructor. The beginning bound must be less than the ending bound."

Comment: And tell me, where I should open an incident? I'm not used to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Check if the input is correct, `select ... start, end where start > end`.

Comment: To open an incident with Teradata support approach your DBA.

Comment: I just checked the input and yes it's correct, in all cases the end is greater than the start.

Here is an example:

START: 731320086100000
END: 731320087099999

Comment: Well, 731320086100000 is definitely outside of the INTEGER range, modified my answer for BIGINTs.

Comment: It works now What can I say: You're my hero :D Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear. Just a final question: Why do you actually need this? Expanding to more than a million rows?

Comment: I have multiple ranges and I need to split them into rows (it is easier for me to analyze them) and some of these ranges can be up to 3 million.

Now if you have a better idea, I'm a taker :D

Comment: It's hard to tell without details, but there's a bunch of nice functionality more advanced than basic SQL (besides OLAP-Functions) like NPath, Time Series, Recursion. And in SQL there are always multiple ways to get the same result :-)

Comment: I tried using the Recursion functions, it gave me the expected result. However, it was too slow compared to what you suggested (using PERIOD + EXPAND ON which by the way gave me what I was looking for in a few seconds).

Comment: Of course, recursion is slow for a large number of repetitions, it's sequential. But it's just preparing the data for the actual analysis. And this analysis might possibly be rewritten using those advanced SQL functios.

Comment: Hey. It's me again² (I hope this is the last time that I'm bothering you).
I just notice something in the script you shared before. In some cases when breaking the ranges into rows, some are having an extra "86400000000".
Example 01: Start: 631321086100000, End: 631321088099999.
Example 02: Start: 630318030100000, End: 630318030101498. (in this case, the script work just fine).

Comment: Hmm, strange, I just tried your example range and it returned 2,000,000 rows as expected and no extra row.

Comment: I think I misspoke. What I was trying to say is for the first example instead of having : 631321086100000, 631321086100001, 631321086100002...etc as rows I'm having this: 631321086100000 + 86400000000 = 631407486100000, 631321086100001 + 86400000000 = 631407486100001. Which is not the case for the second example. Another issue I would like to mention: When trying to cast the result (pd) to VARCHAR, there is an extra "." at the end. Example: "631321086100001."

Comment: This issue was somehow related to the session time zone, there was no easy fix (I hate doing casts/calculations on TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE). Rewrote using my initial approach and borrowed the nice TD_TIME_BUCKET_NUMBER from Teradata 16.20s *Time Series* feature. This should work now, including the type cast to VarChar. The previous result was a DECIMAL instead of a BIGINT. I assumed it would be BIGINT, but was obviously wrong.

Comment: When trying to use the BGINT solution, I'm having this error : "[5407] Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval.". Do you have any idea why?

Comment: You wrote that start/end are strings instead of numeric, you must `CAST(start AS BIGINT)`, etc.

Comment: You're right, that was the issue. Thanks again, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte (n, end) as (
      select start, end
      from t
      union all
      select n + 1, end
      from cte
      where n < end
     )
select n
from cte;
```

Note:  You can include other columns in `cte`, so you can break up each row and still have other information such as an `id` or whatever.