Teradata sql: search in number ranges
There are two tables
TableA with 4million records and TableB with 400k records, there is number field in TableA which I need look up in the TableB in the ranges and get a column from TableB.
TableA
ColumnNum Integer
TableB
ColumnNumLower Integer
ColumnNumHigh  Integer
ColumnOutput   String
select a.ColumnNum , b.ColumnOutput
from TableA a
left join TableB b
on 1=1
and a.ColumnNum between b.ColumnNumLower  and b.ColumnNumHigh  
;

Index are collected on these columns but the query obviously going into the product join and the results are not coming up. Any Idea on how to get the sql working. Would partitions help?
Thanks in Advance.

I see both columns are INTEGER. How wide can the ranges be in TableB? It might be feasible to expand each range to a list of discrete values and join based on equality predicate. And no, I don't think partitions can help here.

Sorry I didn’t understand.

If the difference between ColumnNumLower and ColumnNumHigh in any row is not too large, there are ways to expand to separate rows, each with a single value ColumnNumLower, ColumnNumLower+1, ..., ColumnNumHigh and then do a more efficient join.

If I add the differences of the ranges its coming out as 332m records. In some cases the ranges are 30m apart.

Based on Fred Idea I used dnoeth solution in a similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67984747/break-ranges-into-rows-teradata
